# Rails passing params with link_to using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm creating a online order system for a restaurant using rails and i want to be able to attach modifiers to items using ajax i have

```
<%= link_to(mod.name , add_modifier_url , method: :put, remote: true, mod_id: mod.id, item_id: item.id) %>
```

the call is making it to my controller but i cant access any of the params I'm sending how do you pass params with link_to and ajax in rails

thanks

EDIT

I think I answered my own question, I just had to put the params i wanted to send as params for the url

```
<%= link_to(mod.name , add_modifier_url( mod_id: mod.id, item_id: item.id) , method: :put, remote: true) %>
```

Comment: how did you try to access parameters?

Comment: in my controller I'm accessing them with
     def add_modifier
  Item.find(params[:item_id])
  Modifier.find(params[:mod_id])
 end

Comment: could you please provide the final url from your browsers network console?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/add_modifier?item_id=15&mod_id=7

Comment: if you want that url, then you have to pass those querystrings to your path method. sth like, `action_resource_path(k1: v1, k2: v2 ... kn: vn)`. in your case, this should probably be, `add_modifier_path(item_id: item.id, mod_id: mod.id)`. but better option (i mean more railsesque) is, ofcourse to use nested attributes. e.g. depending the parent-child relation between resources,  `/modifiers/17/item/15`